how do I solve cloud firestore not found error on CodeMagic?
I have built a basic flutter application which has integration of firebase.
I don't have a mac, so iam using a codemagic CI/CD to build the .ipa file for my ios version.
Now i have come across this cloud_firestore not found
Warning: Building for device with codesigning disabled. You will have to manually codesign before deploying to device.
Building com.example.hrms for device (ios-release)...
Updating minimum iOS deployment target to 12.0.
Upgrading Podfile
Running pod install...                                           1,256ms
Running Xcode build...                                          
Xcode build done.                                           86.4s
Failed to build iOS app
Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'cloud_firestore' not found
/Users/runner/work/hrms-ios/hrms-ios/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:11:8
Encountered error while building for device.

below is my Podfile contents
platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'Runner' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Runner

  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

i have been trying to solve this error past one day
